# How to completely delete and recreate thinking-sphinx index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am using the thinking-sphinx plugin for a ruby on rails app. In testing and development, I have reindexed many, many times, sometimes against different databases, with the result that now all of my searches return an empty array. I don't believe this is related to the codebase, because other developers using the same code can get valid search results on their own machines.

My question is, is there some way to completely remove the existing index (either from Sphinx or Thinking Sphinx) and start over completely from scratch? None of the documentation seems to tell exactly "where" the index is, or how to delete it and create a new one.

Answer (score 3):

For thinking sphinx you could try `rake ts:rebuild`

http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/rake_tasks.html